# How to modify syslog output format in busybox?

Tags: logging, embedded-linux, syslog, busybox

How to modify syslog output format in busybox?
For example:

Jan  1 00:00:42 LSM user.info root: Hello

to

Jan  1 [IP] LSM user.info root: Hello

I try using template in syslog.conf but it not works. ref. http://goo.gl/tcDbzZ

```
$template precise,"%syslogpriority%,%syslogfacility%,%timegenerated%,%HOSTNAME%,%syslogtag%,%msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate precise
```

Or should I modify the syslog.c in src? Is there a better way to achieve this work?

Thanks for your help and kindness.

Answer (score 1):

syslog in busybox has an option FEATURE_SYSLOGD_CFG which can enable/disable at compile time the support of syslog.conf.

Note that it is surely a restricted support compared to "standard" syslog.conf.

check if this option is enabled with `make menuconfig`

Comment: I have checked the make menuconfig, it has been activated. It seems busybox doesn't support syslog template in loggeing messages.

Answer (score 1):

There are several "syslog".

For BusyBox it's the "classic" **syslogd**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog

For Ubuntu, it's the **rsyslog**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsyslog

For some other systems, it's the **syslog-ng**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng

The link you specified as ref. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/79684/syslog-not-showing-log-levels-in-messages) is for Ubuntu, so **rsyslog**.

I think you can't use templates like that with **syslogd**.

Answer (score 0):

Busybox by default uses syslogd in /sbin, you can check in /etc/init.d/S01logging, which ignores all the configuration you make at syslog.conf.

Actually, it has another "fully-functional" syslogd, which resides at /usr/sbin/. I suggest you modified S01logging script to start this new syslogd and test if your configs works.